# Doubles/printing not able to handle 14 digits in C++

Tags: c++, variables, size, double

This is probably a stupid question, but I seem to be running into a situation where doubles are not functioning as I would expect, but everything I've seen says that they are 64-bit and should be able to handle more than 10 digits.

```
long double test = 44398048390843;
printf("%Ld \n", test);
printf("%d \n", test);
```

But every time it prints like this:

```
Output:
-209183936
-209183936
```

I'm assuming that there is something stupid I'm missing, but can someone give me an idea what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified the wrong format string (twice). For `long double` you use `%Lf`:

```
printf("%Lf \n", test);
```

Note that `%Ld` is undefined, and that `%d` is for decimal formatted output, and expects an `int` argument.

However, in C++, you should use `cout`, and avoid this confusion:

```
std::cout << test << " \n";
```

Comment: +1. As long as this question is tagged C++, the *Right Thing®* is to use streams for your textual I/O, not those error-prone printf/scanf routines.

Comment: As a note to myself, I failed to mention the more exotic floating point formatting specifiers: `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `g`, `G`, and `F`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `printf("%Lf", test);`

However, you marked your question as C++. Here you can use [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) for streams.